# can't insert default text into TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text-editor

So I am creating a text editor using TKinter. I have the basics down and now I am trying to create a button where when you press it, you select a file and it opens it. From what I have seen the insert method would be best for Entry widget. But i am using Label widget and it does not work for some reason. Here is my code so far:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk 
frame = tk.Tk() 
frame.title("Fake Google Docs") 
frame.geometry('800x600') 

inputtxt = tk.Text(frame, 
                height = 25, 
                width = 90) 

inputtxt.pack() 

global file
 
#this is function to be executed when u press first button
def printInput(): 
  filename = input("Name of the file make sure you end with .txt")
  file = open(filename, 'w')
  result=inputtxt.get("1.0","end")
  file.write(result) 
  file.close()
  
#this is function to be executed for open new file thing
def printInputnew(): 
  filenamemm = input("Name of the file make sure you end with .txt")
  file = open(filenamemm, 'w')
  result=inputtxt.get("1.0","end")
  file.write("") 
  file.close()

def openfile(): 
  filenamem = input("Name of the file you want to open")
  tru=open(filenamem)
  if tru== False:
    sys.exit() 
  else:
    f = open(filenamem, "r")
    for x in f:
      print(x)
      name=str(x)
    text = tk.StringVar() 
    text.set(name) 
    
 #button 1
printButton = tk.Button(frame, 
                        text = "Save to text file", 
                        command = printInput) 
printButton.pack() 

printButtonl = tk.Button(frame, 
                        text = "open a file", 
                        command = openfile) 
printButtonl.pack() 
#button 2
printButton = tk.Button(frame, 
                        text = "Open new file", 
                        command = printInputnew) 
printButton.pack() 
#open the text box
lbl = tk.Label(frame, textvariable = "") 
lbl.pack() 

 #finish code
frame.mainloop()
```

Could someone else suggest a method for inserting text into this widget?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "does not work". Do you get an error? Does it insert the text in the wrong place? Have you read the documentation enough to know that setting the value of a label is completely different from setting the value of an entry widget?

Comment: yes I know but At the point I was desperate for anything too work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```py
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

frame = tk.Tk()
frame.title("Fake Google Docs")
frame.geometry('800x600')

inputtxt = tk.Text(frame,
                   height=25,
                   width=90)

inputtxt.pack()

global file

mask = [("Text and Python files", "*.txt *.py *.pyw *.rcad"),
             ("HTML files", "*.htm"),
             ("All files", "*.*")]


# this is function to be executed when u press first button
def printInput():
    filename = input("Name of the file make sure you end with .txt")
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    result = inputtxt.get("1.0", "end")
    file.write(result)
    file.close()


# this is function to be executed for open new file thing
def printInputnew():
    filenamemm = input("Name of the file make sure you end with .txt")
    file = open(filenamemm, 'w')
    result = inputtxt.get("1.0", "end")
    file.write("")
    file.close()


def openfile():
    filenamem = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=mask)
    tru = open(filenamem)
    if tru == False:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        f = open(filenamem, "r")
        inputtxt.delete(0.0, 'end')
        inputtxt.insert('end', f.read())

        # button 1


printButton = tk.Button(frame,
                        text="Save to text file",
                        command=printInput)
printButton.pack()

printButtonl = tk.Button(frame,
                         text="open a file",
                         command=openfile)
printButtonl.pack()
# button 2
printButton = tk.Button(frame,
                        text="Open new file",
                        command=printInputnew)
printButton.pack()
# open the text box
lbl = tk.Label(frame, textvariable="")
lbl.pack()

# finish code
frame.mainloop()
```

I changed this block of code:

```py
def openfile():
    filenamem = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=mask)
    tru = open(filenamem)
    if tru == False:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        f = open(filenamem, "r")
        inputtxt.delete(0.0, 'end')
        inputtxt.insert('end', f.read())
```

It opens a window that ask you which file you want to open. `askopenfilename` method returns a string path to selected file. Then you just read whole file, delete whole text that you had in your `tk.Text` object and paste there text from opened file. That is all :)
And please, next time watch some guides about `tkinter` before asking and read about PEP8.

Comment: Please try to avoid txtspk while typing answers, and consider giving a bit of explanation too.

Comment: for the first time I see that I was reproached for it. Anyway ok :)

Comment: Well take read down [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105497/how-to-deal-with-user-using-txt-spk) too. I was once corrected for the same issue before, so deal with it :p

Comment: This answer would be better if you included an explanation. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.

Comment: you are satisfied now?